# Server Side Datatable, Show foreign key name

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, foreign-keys, server-side

I don't know if this is really hard or not but I'm trying to show on my datatable the name of 2 Foreign key's

```
Table |tipo|    |marca|    |producto|
name  |nombre|  |nombre|   |id_tipo |
                           |id_marca|
```

index.blade function:

```
$(function () {
    oDtable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "order": [12, 'desc'],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": ["copy", "xls", "csv", "print"]
        },
        "ajax": "/ajax/getJSONResultsForDT?table=productos&primaryKey=id",
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "descripcion"},
            {"data": "id_tipo"}, //HERE I want to show the name of the exactly tipo on the datatable
            {"data": "id_marca"}, // same with marca
            {"data": "precio_compra"},
            {"data": "precio_compra_unidad_medida"},
            {"data": "precio_compra_total_unitario"},
            {"data": "precio_compra_neto"},
            {"data": "precio_venta"},
            {"data": "precio_venta_unidad_medida"},
            {"data": "precio_venta_total_unitario"},
            {"data": "precio_venta_neto"},
            {"data": "created_at"},
            {"data": null},
            {"data": null}
        ],
});
```

I handle all the tables on a controller this way:

AjaxController:

```
case "productos":
            $columns = array(
                array('db' => 'id', 'dt' => 'id'),
                array('db' => 'id_tipo', 'dt' => 'id_tipo'),
                array('db' => 'id_marca', 'dt' => 'id_marca'),
                array('db' => 'descripcion', 'dt' => 'descripcion'),
                array('db' => 'precio_compra', 'dt' => 'precio_compra'),
                array('db' => 'precio_compra_unidad_medida', 'dt' => 'precio_compra_unidad_medida'),
                array('db' => 'precio_compra_total_unitario', 'dt' => 'precio_compra_total_unitario'),
                array('db' => 'precio_compra_neto', 'dt' => 'precio_compra_neto'),
                array('db' => 'precio_venta', 'dt' => 'precio_venta'),
                array('db' => 'precio_venta_unidad_medida', 'dt' => 'precio_venta_unidad_medida'),
                array('db' => 'precio_venta_total_unitario', 'dt' => 'precio_venta_total_unitario'),
                array('db' => 'precio_venta_neto', 'dt' => 'precio_venta_neto'),
                array('db' => 'precio_publico', 'dt' => 'precio_publico'),
                array('db' => 'created_at', 'dt' => 'created_at'),
            );
            break;
```

Example:

[image]

Else to show the id_tipo and id_marca want show the name.

So, I don't know if I can show the tipo and marca name on the databtale declared on the index.blade or on the Ajaxcontroller.

Can someone help me please, any help will be apreciated.